# How can I source a R file and store all variables from the file in a list

Tags: r

Hello I would like to source a R file and that all variables defined in the file  be stored in a list without any other environment to be affected

```
# my_file.R
x = 1
y = 2
z = x + y
t = 'test'
```

I'd like to get something like `p <- source_in_list("my_file.R")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `local` parameter for `source` to save the results in an environment.  Here's a function that wraps it up and converts the environment into a list:

```
source_in_list <- function(path) {
  e <- new.env()
  source(path, local = e)
  as.list(e)
}
```